# T-SQL compare two tables values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables.

First table:

```
Name     Cost
house 1  10000
house 2  5000
house 3  100
```

Second table:

```
Type From     To
A   1.00      1000.00
B   1000.10   10000.00
С   10000.10  100000.00
```

How to build third table that should be looking like.

```
Name     Cost  Type
house 1  10000 C
house 2  5000  B
house 3  100   A
```

Comment: `house 1` should be type B

Comment: What if a house costs 10000.05? It would have no corresponding type in the second table?

Comment: @GarethD  This is probably acceptable for his particular requirements, but I have issue with it as well.  I will post an alternative answer for folks who may want to cover this potential future 'hole'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
SELECT t.*, r.Type
FROM t           -- first table
LEFT JOIN r      -- second table
  ON t.Cost BETWEEN r.[From] AND r.[To];
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/ZAVVC88628)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

For the case when precision is indeterminate, for example with decimals from a computation or datetimes, you can use a 'type' table with a single threshold value.

```
Type From
A   1.00 
B   1000.10
С   10000.10

Select T1.Name, T1.Cost, Table2.Type
    From
        (
        Select  [From] Threshold, IsNull(Lead(From) Over (Order By From), (Some max value maybe 100000000)) NextThreshold 
            From Table2) T2
    Join Table1 T1 On T1.Cost >= T2.Threshold And T1.Cost < T2.NextThreshold
```